# symfony2 Entity Object vs. integer crashes

Tags: symfony, object, doctrine, entity

I have defined a entity like :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")

 */
private $client_id;

.....

public function setClientId($clientId = null)
{
    $this->client_id = $clientId;

    return $this;
}
```

There are two controllers with which I can create a new db entry. the first one is "admin-only" where the admin can create a db entry with a client id of his choice:

```
->add('client_id', 'entity', array(
                                   'data_class' => null,
                                   'attr' => array(
                                                   'class' => 'selectstyle'),
                                   'class' => 'PrUserBundle:Client',
                                   'property' => 'name',
                                   'required' => true,
                                   'label'  => 'staff.location',
                                   'empty_value' => 'admin.customer_name',
                                   'empty_data'  => null
                                   )
     )

   ......
    // Handling the form
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $saniType->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
        $saniType->setClientId($form->get('client_id')->getData());
        $saniType->setCreated(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:m:s')));
        $saniType->setCreatedBy($user->getUsername());
        $em->persist($saniType);
        $em->flush();
```

The second one is for the client itself, where he's not able to set a different client id. Therefor I just removed the form field "client_id" and replace it by the users->getClientId():

```
$saniType->setSpecialClientId($form->get('client_id')->getData());
```

When I add an entry as admin, it work fine. If I try to add one as "client", it crashes with following error message

```
 Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given in /var/www/symfony/webprojekt/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 1389
```

I'm a newby in symfony, so I haven't got the strength to figure out what happens. I only knew that in the first case, admin will submit a object (entity). In the second (client) case, I set an integer as I get one by

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Is there a solution for it so that I can handle entity object AND given integers like it comes when the client add an entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change you relation defnition to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")

 */
private $client;

.....

public function setClient($client = null)
{
    $this->client = $client;

   return $this;
}
```

Then in form:

```
->add('client', 'entity', array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'selectstyle'),
        'class' => 'PrUserBundle:Client',
        'property' => 'name',
        'required' => true,
        'label'  => 'staff.location',
        'empty_value' => 'admin.customer_name',
        'empty_data'  => null
    )
)
```

Handling the form:

```
form = $this->createForm(new SaniType(), $entity);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // perform some action...

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_success'));
}
```

More about handling form: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

---

Also worth nothing:

for auto update properties like createdBy / updatedBy i would recommend you to use Doctrine Extension: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/blameable.md

Comment: OK I changed it. There is also an error in my code cause I supposed to create an db entry as a client with this: $saniType->setClient($this->clientId); now, I get another error :( Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Pr\SensorBundle\Entity\SanitationType::setClient() must be an instance of Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Client,

Comment: What I mean is, if there is an ManyToOne an I will deliver a integer for the reason that i dont include the client selction in the form, how can I hanlde this?

Comment: Instead of:
  $saniType->setClient($this->clientId)
call:
  $saniType->setClient($client)

where $client is to Client entity object.
If you only have clientId you can always get Client object with Repository.

Comment: oh, ok. The CleintId came from the User security token cause every user is assigned to a client by it's id. Tehre for, in the case of adding a new entry as "client" I have only my assigned cleint number from my user security token.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to know the client id. You have to set the Client himself.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $client;

.....

public function setClient(\Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Client $client = null)
{
    $this->client = $client;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution:

[Symfony2: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968679/symfony2-spl-object-hash-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-string-given-in-do)

It's a workaround but it's ok for the moment.