# Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

One of the many of these questions... I'll try to make it clear.

first, the error:

```
at UnitOfWork ->computeAssociationChanges (array('fieldName' => 'currencyNumerator', 'joinColumns' => array(array('name' => 'currencyNumerator_id', 'referencedColumnName' => 'id')), 'cascade' => array(), 'inversedBy' => null, 'targetEntity' => 'NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Currency', 'fetch' => '2', 'type' => '2', 'mappedBy' => null, 'isOwningSide' => true, 'sourceEntity' => 'NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\CurrencyValuation', 'isCascadeRemove' => false, 'isCascadePersist' => false, 'isCascadeRefresh' => false, 'isCascadeMerge' => false, 'isCascadeDetach' => false, 'sourceToTargetKeyColumns' => array('currencyNumerator_id' => 'id'), 'joinColumnFieldNames' => array('currencyNumerator_id' => 'currencyNumerator_id'), 'targetToSourceKeyColumns' => array('id' => 'currencyNumerator_id'), 'orphanRemoval' => false), '1')
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 687  +
```

this occurs when I'm trying to persist an object currencyValuation.

But then here is a print of the object just before I persist it:

```
object(stdClass)#531 (6) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(57) "NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\CurrencyValuation"
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["value"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["campaignAssigned"]=>
  object(stdClass)#643 (12) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(48) "NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Campaign"
    ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["number"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "ActualsJAN2015"
    ["status"]=>
    string(11) "in progress"
    ["fiscalYear"]=>
    int(2015)
    ["version"]=>
    int(1)
    ["cycle"]=>
    string(60) "Proxies\__CG__\NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Cycle"
    ["period"]=>
    string(61) "Proxies\__CG__\NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Period"
    ["customer"]=>
    string(58) "Proxies\__CG__\NRtworks\SubscriptionBundle\Entity\Customer"
  }
  ["currencyNumerator"]=>
  object(stdClass)#654 (5) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(48) "NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Currency"
    ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "EUR"
  }
  ["currencyDenominator"]=>
  object(stdClass)#652 (3) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(48) "NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Currency"
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "CNY"
  }
}
```

to finish with, a part of my class:

```
 class CurrencyValuation implements JsonSerializable
    {
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8)
     */

    protected $value;  


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Campaign")
     */
    protected $campaignAssigned;  

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Currency")
     */
    protected $currencyNumerator;  

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NRtworks\BusinessDimensionBundle\Entity\Currency")
     */
    protected $currencyDenominator;     
       }
```

As you can see, I'm not giving it an integer, there are only objects in it. I was wondering if it could be the fact that these classes are proxies. Can it ? Or is there something I don't see ?

Comment: It is unlikely for the problem to be caused by proxies, their purpose is to provide a way to connect two objects. The problem must be somewhere else. Could you provide the way you set **currencyNumerator** either by calling ->setCurrencyNumerator() or your definition in a FormType?

Comment: I noticed the lack of `@JoinColumn` relationship definitions. If these relations are inverse-side objects (which is unlikely, as far as I could tell) you would need to set `mappedBy` option.

Did you really leave `@JoinColumn` on purpose or?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968679/symfony2-spl-object-hash-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-string-given-in-do?rq=1

Comment: @Andariel yes with ->setCurrencyNumerator()

Comment: @Jovan Perovic I have no join column explicitely defined  nor mapped by (I don't want it). Can that be the problem ? Not sure.

Comment: JoinColumn is optional by default. @Eagle1, can you paste exactly how you set the object?